# Automate SQL case statement and left joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, automation, case

Looking to improve upon this code, it actually works as is but it isn't efficient. In these two pieces of SQL code, the case statement is manually updated to include new vehicles along with the multiple left joins. If I were to add another vehicle for instance, I would add:

`,case when F.[vehicle] is null then 'Up' else 'Down' end as car_truck`

If I wanted to update the left join after updating the case statement it would look like:

```
          (SELECT  [vehicles]
      ,[entity_state_list]
  FROM [SCDA].[Availablity].[vw_XEUS]
  where vehicles ='car_truck') F
             on A.entity_state=E.[entity_state_list]
             left outer join
```

It is time consuming to add these every time there is a new vehicle. I am looking to have code that updates vehicles automatically and assigns an alias so no manual input needs to occur for both case statements and left joins.

```
select A.* 
,case when B.[vehicle] is null then 'Up' else 'Down' end as cars
,case when C.[vehicles] is null then 'Up' else 'Down' end as trucks
,case when D.[vehicles] is null then 'Up' else 'Down' end as electric
,case when E.[vehicles] is null then 'Up' else 'Down' end as hybrid

 

 left outer join 
             (SELECT  [vehicles]
      ,[entity_state_list]
  FROM [SCDA].[Availablity].[vw_XEUS]
  where vehicles ='cars') B
             on A.entity_state=B.entity_state_list
             left outer join 
             (SELECT  [vehicles]
      ,[entity_state_list]
  FROM [SCDA].[Availablity].[vw_XEUS]
  where vehicles ='trucks') C
             on A.entity_state=C.[entity_state_list]
             left outer join 
             (SELECT  [vehicles]
      ,[entity_state_list]
  FROM [SCDA].[Availablity].[vw_XEUS]
  where vehicles ='electric') D
             on A.entity_state=D.[entity_state_list]
             left outer join 
            (SELECT  [vehicles]
      ,[entity_state_list]
  FROM [SCDA].[Availablity].[vw_XEUS]
  where vehicles ='hybrid') E
             on A.entity_state=E.[entity_state_list]
             left outer join
```

The desired end result would be case statements and left joins that require no manual intervention. The code as it is today does work but isn't efficient. In another language like Python, my approach would to write a loop, but I do not know how to do that in SQL.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for both your "A" table and `[SCDA].[Availablity].[vw_XEUS]`? Given that you want dynamic columns, I'm not sure there will be a good way to automate your `SELECT` clause without using dynamic SQL, but I suspect you can probably avoid writing all of those left-joins.